# Does setting listen to false on StreamProvider prevent cloud firestore read charge?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using the provider architecture, more specifically, the StreamProvider, to get a list of documents
in a collection called 'Timeline Posts'. One of my goals is to minimize firestore reads and hence costs, so my question is:

If I set listen=false, I know this prevents my UI from updating when there's an update in the documents but does it also prevent firestore from reading that update and charging it as one read. Because I know everytime a document is updated and you're using stream, it counts as a read.

So does listen=false affect both my UI in flutter and the firestore read

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you with this issue? I believe that you can have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) for Cloud Firestore pricing breakdown and an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example).

Comment: @sllopis thanks! I finally ended up using features. after much reading, although streams can be very useful ,turns out streams arent always the best cost wise with firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation it will still read the changes in the stream. You could switch to a FutureProvider in order to prevent this from happening. If you share your code I would be happy to help you make that switch. A future is something you only would like to read one time and a stream is used for tracking real-time changes.

Comment: I'm definitely going with the Future. thansk you, appreciate the help..luckily I had a separate database service class and I'm using multiprovider so I just had ti change a few things like 'snapshots()' to 'getDocuments' and then use FutureProvider!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Futures instead? I generally use Futures instead of Stream for the situation you are describing.

Comment: Hmm, yeah right now I don't see any disadvantages to using Futures for this situation. I'll probably resort to futureprovider. But still curious, though.